# Laravel leftJoin error Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to take out "superadmins" by using this controller:

```
$user->superadmin = DB::table('role_users AS ru')
->leftJoin('users AS u', 'u.id', '=', 'ru.user_id')
->where('role_id', '=', '5')
->select("u.*")
->get('');
```

And blade:

```
@foreach ($user->superadmin as $superadmin)
{{ $superadmin->username }}
@endforeach
```

**"users"** table have a unique **ID**. That unique ID is the same as **role_users.user_id**.

But i'm getting error:

**Creating default object from empty value**

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user->superadmin = ...;
```

> Creating default object from empty value

You need to define `$user` as some object before trying to set a property on it (using it like an object).

```
$user = new stdClass;
$user->superadmin = ...;
```

I am not sure what type you are expecting `$user` to be besides some object.

Comment: Oh my gash... What a stupid mistake i do! `$user = user();` THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

remove `get(' ')` from get as `''` it selects an empty value

```
$user->superadmin = DB::table('role_users AS ru')
->leftJoin('users AS u', 'u.id', '=', 'ru.user_id')
->where('role_id', '=', '5')
->select("u.*")
->get();
```

To get users with the specific role id :

```
User::with(['role_users'=>function($user) use($someId){
     $user->where('role_id', $someId);
}]);
```

Comment: Hm... Same thing after remove `' '`

Comment: Changed to `->whereIn('role_id', '=', '5')` and now getting **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I'm trying takeout all users info who have **rolde_id 5**

Comment: also $user->superadmin = query it does not make sens at all.

Comment: Thanks for helping. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: @MyndeMindaugelis make sure you wrapp it on an array  with(['role_users'=> function()...])

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$user->superadmin = DB::table('role_users')->select(['users.*'])
            ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'role_users.user_id')
            ->where('role_users.role_id','5')
            ->get();
```